# ERT code not working in a particular document

Tags: lyx, code

I wanted to use biber as a bibliography processor in Lyx and that involves some manual settings as explained [here](http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex) .

The last bit invloves inserting a LaTeX command \printbibliography in ERT (TeX mode). However, I noticed that the code appears in blue colour instead of the red and it does not work either.

I am wondering what could cause the problem as the simple example works fine i.e. Lyx is not the problem but it is something in the document (preamble, cls, layout. etc.) that may cause this issue.

Is there any way to figure out what is the culprit? I am using a University of Toronto class and layout which can be found [here](http://theorie.physik.uni-konstanz.de/jrioux/lyx/)

The visual behaviour can be seen in this screenshot (notice that the code is blue and not red):

[image]

Any help and ideas on how to fix this issue are highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: this looks strange. Let's hope some experienced LyX user sees this and can help.

Comment: Please show us the complete LaTeX Source of a  minimal working example (well, really a not-working example, but complete and minimal).

Comment: @Fran Unfortunately, as I said a minimal example works (see the link). The problem is with the big one, which I cannot share, I wanted just some hints about how to debug this thing. Thanks

Comment: @Bogdan We do not need see your confidencial text,  a only copy  where **all** stuff no related with the problem is removed  ("minimal"), including superfluous code in LaTeX preamble. Using LyX,  the exported  LaTeX source always maintain the document structure, and in this sense is  "complete",   so that we can reproduce your ouput/errors and understand/solve your problem.  Otherwise is a shooting blind-game, for example ..."I guess that could be  blue because is between a chunk of text in another language".

Comment: @Fran I tried but I can't create a small file that reproduces the problem. I ended up creating an empty lyx file and copied all the text from the old file into the new one.  And the ERT code worked. For a while. Now when I try to create a new codes I run into the same problem. I suspect some sort of bug in lyx. That's why I asked how can I debug such things jut to avoid blind games.

Comment: @Bogdan Take your time to fully understand [what is a minimal working example (MWE)](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) and the [strategies for reducing your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). This is the only safe way where we can help. You ***always*** can take the LaTeX source and remove parts until the problem is solved (= you have found where is the problem)  or there are new errors.  If the latter happen, go back and try again, now without break definitions, commands or dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After copying twice the text in a new file and having again the ERT codes working I finally understood what is causing the problem. It is not the size of my text or anything to do with weird characters that I may have introduced while adding new text as I initially thought.

**The problem appears** when I enable *Document->Change Tracking ->Track Changes.* After disabling track changes ERT codes appear in red.

**This is normal** as the ERT code is viewed as new text which normally appear in blue when tracking is enabled because they are viewed as text changes. This appearance looked unfamiliar and was misleading. I thought that something is wrong with the ERT code generation because at the same time the code did not work..

The reason for which the ERT code did not work initially had other roots and had something to do with paths pointing to the wrong files.

I post this explanation here with the hope that will help someone who is fooled by appearances instead looking for the real causes.